# Android Manifest file calling the other java program

Tags: android, xml

My Android Manifest file is like below and its not calling MainLauncher as a first activity instead of that its calling MultilevelTreeListView.  I don't know the reason. I removed the 
below statement for MultiLeveltreelistview, but nothing appears in that case.

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jd.multileveltreelistview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
            android:name="com.jd.multileveltreelistview.MainLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.jd.multileveltreelistview.MultilevelTreeListView"
            android:label="@string/hello_world" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainLauncher.Java

```
package com.jd.multileveltreelistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainLauncher extends Activity{
    LinearLayout lm;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


       ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
       //imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.cigna);


        lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
        lm.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        TextView product3 = new TextView(this);
        product3.setText("\n");
        lm.addView(product3);  


        String[] ClearRow =  { "Enter" };
        LinearLayout InitRow = new LinearLayout(this);
           InitRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
           createButtonsreset(InitRow, ClearRow, 1);

         TextView product2 = new TextView(this);
         product2.setText("           ");
            //product2.setTextColor(color.holo_blue_dark);
         lm.addView(product2);

         String[] ClearRow1 = { "Instructions" };
         LinearLayout InitRow1 = new LinearLayout(this);
         InitRow1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
         createButtonsreset(InitRow1, ClearRow1, 1);

             }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);  
        this.finish();    
    }

    private void createButtonsreset(LinearLayout layoutToAddButtonsTo, String[] itemsToAdd, int Lengthvalue) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Lengthvalue; i++) {
            final Button buttonToAdd = new Button(this);
            buttonToAdd.setText("  "+itemsToAdd[i]);
            buttonToAdd.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
            buttonToAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);

            // buttonToAdd.setWidth(50);
           buttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   
                    String Strvalue = (String) buttonToAdd.getText();
                    if (Strvalue.equals("  "+"Enter"))
                    {       DrawShapes1();   }
                   }
            });
           layoutToAddButtonsTo.addView(buttonToAdd);

        }
        // In the end add all buttons inside the inner LinearLayout to the outer LinearLayout.
        lm.addView(layoutToAddButtonsTo);
    }

    public void DrawShapes1() {
        Intent activityIntent = 
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(activityIntent);
    }
}
```

And MultiLevelTreeview

```
package com.jd.multileveltreelistview;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MultilevelTreeListView extends Activity 
{
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView mainList;
    ArrayList<Entity>arrTrades;
    public static int cnt = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.treelist);
        mainList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.currentpending_list);
        mainList.setDividerHeight(10);
        arrTrades=new ArrayList<Entity>();
        mainList.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cigna);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        if(arrTrades.size()==0){
            populateList();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    public Entity getEntity(int level,int haschild){
        Entity E=new Entity();
        //System.out.println("INGU VANTHEN");
        E.Name="Level "+level;
        if (cnt == 0 )
        {
            E.Name=" Debanjan Dev";
        }
        if (cnt == 1 )
        {
            E.Name=" S Viswanathan";
        }
        if (cnt == 2 )
        {
            E.Name=" Sanjay Manot";
        }
        if (cnt == 3 )
        {
            E.Name=" Manoj Tripati";
        }       
        if (cnt == 4 )
        {
            E.Name=" Narayanan";
        }
        if (cnt == 5 )
        {
            E.Name=" Sukumaran Chandrasingh";
        }
        if (cnt == 6 )
        {
            E.Name=" Jothi Ganesh";
        }       
        if (cnt == 7 )
        {
            E.Name=" Jesupillai Jacob ";
        }       
        if (cnt == 8 )
        {
            E.Name=" Vinodh Ramadoss ";
        }
        if (cnt == 9 )
        {
            E.Name=" Paul Chellappa ";
        }
        if (cnt == 10 )
        {
            E.Name=" Subramani Sundaramurthi ";
        }


        cnt = cnt+1;
        Log.d("details","Inguvanthen");
        E.isOpened=false;
        E.level=level;
        E.HasChild=haschild;
        return E;
    }
    public void populateList()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                    arrTrades.add(getEntity(0, 1));
            }
            adapter=new ListAdapter(MultilevelTreeListView.this, R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel, arrTrades);
            mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(" populateList Exception",""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void CellButtonClick(View v){
        try{
            Button b=(Button)v;
            int index;
            index=(Integer) b.getTag();
            if(b.getText().toString().equals("+")){
                b.setText("-");

                Entity temp[]=new Entity[3];
                int PLevel=arrTrades.get(index).level+1;
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                    temp[i]=getEntity(PLevel, 1);
                }
                arrTrades.get(index).isOpened=true;
                if(temp!=null){
                    int addindex=index+1;
                    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                        arrTrades.add(addindex, temp[i]);
                        addindex++;
                    }
                }
                temp=null;
            }
            else{
                b.setText("+");
                cnt = cnt - 3;
                arrTrades.get(index).isOpened=false;
                    int removeindex=index+1;
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                        if(arrTrades.get(removeindex).isOpened){
                            removeChilds(removeindex);
                        }
                        arrTrades.remove(removeindex);
                    }
                }


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("Error=", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void removeChilds(int index){
        try {
                int removeindex=index+1;
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                    if(arrTrades.get(removeindex).isOpened){
                        removeChilds(removeindex);
                    }
                    arrTrades.remove(removeindex);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Errro=", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

This should only be for one activity that u want start at start up of ur activity, remove for MultilevelTreeListView

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

from your `MultilevelTreeListView` in your Android Manifest.

Also change the word DEFAULT for LAUNCHER in your `MainLauncher` activity

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.jd.multileveltreelistview.MainLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.jd.multileveltreelistview.MultilevelTreeListView"
        android:label="@string/hello_world" >
    </activity>
```